# ValueError: could not convert string to float — user input with Python

Tags: python, string, input

I'm trying to write a 'while' loop that takes a users input, if it is a number it remembers it, if it is a blank space it breaks. At the end it should print the average of all entered numbers. This is giving me the error 'could not convert string to float: '. What exactly is wrong here? Thanks!

EDIT: I re-wrote it like this and I get the same error about converting, but it seems to be on the final (count += 1) line?

```
number = 0.0
count = 0

while True:
    user_number = input('Enter a number: ')
    if user_number == ' ':
        break
        print (number / count)
    number = number + float(user_number)
    count += 1
```

Comment: The issue is in the order, even if you enter blank space, you still try to convert it to float in - `number = number + float(user_number)` .

Comment: Do your check first, then add.

Comment: Is the user entering characters other than `' '` and numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you directly hit enter when you don't want to pass numbers anymore. In that case, comparing with a space is incorrect.

```
number = 0.0
count = 0

while True:
    user_number = input('Enter a number: ')
    if user_number == '':
        break

    number += float(user_number)
    count += 1

print (number / count)
```

Also a statement after a `break` is unreachable.

---

If you want a cleaner alternative, I would recommend appending to a list, and then computing the average. This removes the need for a separate counter. Try this:

```
numbers = []
while True:
    user_number = input('Enter a number: ')
    if user_number == '':
        break            

    numbers.append(float(user_number))

print (sum(numbers) / len(numbers))
```

Additionally, you could remove the need for a `break` by testing in the head of `while`, but you'll need to take an additional input outside the loop.

Comment: Ah, that's it! It wasn't a blank space, just nothing! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the order, right now you try to convert everything into floats, even blank spaces.

```
while True:
    user_number = input('Enter a number: ')
    if not user_number.isdigit():
        print (number / count)
        break
    count += 1
    number = number + float(user_number)
```

Additionally, you should do the print of the average value before the `break`.

I changed your if condition to break if any input except a number is entered, it should be a bit more general than before.

Comment: @G3ck0 I changed it to break when anything except a number is entered. It accounts for cases where other string than numbers and blank spaces are used.

Comment: It's a program for uni, weekly exercises. Nothing will one entered other than numbers or a blank space.

Answer (score 0):

Change order and it should solve the problem, you should first check is enterned input is string or not then go to number part

```
#!/usr/bin/python
number = 0.0
count = 0

while True:
    user_number = raw_input('Enter a number: ')
    if user_number == (' '):        
        print (number / count)
    break
    number = number + float(user_number)
    count += 1
```

Comment: Even that still gives me the 'could not convert string to float:' error...

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
lst= []
while True:
user_number = input('Enter a number: ')
if user_number == ' ':
    break
lst.append(int(user_number))
print(int(user_number))
print("Average : " + str(sum(lst)/len(lst)))
```

Comment: and what you think my posting similar answer?

Comment: It certainly does not work, because it suffers from severe formatting and indentation problems.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ.. you are right , my code has indentation issues as it appears here..because i am new to this community and not exactly sure how to put my working code in the comments. I apologize, but my code certainly works perfect, i have tested it before posting the code..please apply appropriate indentation to my code..it will work

Answer (score 0):

This code works correctly. 
I think you are giving Other than space as input to break.

```
number = 0.0
count = 0

while True:
    user_number = input('Enter a number: ')
    if user_number == ' ':
        break
        print (number / count)
    number = number + float(user_number)
    count += 1
```

or else use below code:
--> Break will be triggered for non-digit input.

```
number = 0.0
count = 0
while True:
    user_number = input('Enter a number: ')
    if not user_number.isdigit():
        break
    number = number + float(user_number)
    count += 1
print("user_number", number)
print("Count", count)
print (number / count)
```